# Why does the add method from EF still add duplicates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, duplicates, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add a new machine to the database with an existing customer, but the customer is added to the database as a duplicate each time.

**Code:**

```
public bool Create(ConfiguratedMachine entity)
 {
     int addedRecords;
     using (var ctx = _dbContext)
     {
         var cus = ctx.Customers.Find(3);
         ctx.Customers.Attach(cus);
         var configmach = ctx.ConfiguratedMachines.Add(entity.ToContextModel());

         addedRecords = ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
     return addedRecords > 0;
  }
```

**Database results:**
[image: duplicate customers]

The customer table has a identity(1,1), is that interfering maybe? I mean it should be possible to add even if there's an auto increment on a column right?

**Debugging results:**

This picture shows that there is really a customer with id 3 in the database
[image: debugger on customer find]

This picture shows that the existing customer is attached, but has an error which is unclear to me [not to worry about described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/)
[image: debugger on attach]

This shows the machine is added with the customer
[image: debugger on machine add]

This shows there are 2 records added so the customer and machine...
[image: debugger on records added]

What am I doing wrong? [EF 6 about Attach method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you've got it quite right. The point of the attach method is to have the context track changes to an entity that was previously untracked. There is no reason to call attach on an entity you've just fetched from the DB using the context. You should either get the existing customer using the find method, or attach a newly created customer entity with the correct ID. The latter solution will avoid a round-trip to the DB if the only purpose of the operation is to assign a relationship between the customer and the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake, I was trying to cast from context model to a domain model. The point in that was the new objects that are created to cast from one to another.

**Ugly fast solution:**

```
public bool Create(ConfiguratedMachine entity)
        {
            int addedRecords;
            using (var ctx = _dbContext)
            {
                var cus = ctx.Customers.Find(3);
                ctx.Customers.Attach(cus);
                var configMachine = entity.ToContextModel();
                configMachine.Customer = cus;
                var configmach = ctx.ConfiguratedMachines.Add(configMachine);
                addedRecords = ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            return addedRecords > 0;
        }
```